# How to skip special / socket files during rsync transfer?

Tags: rsync, backup, devices, special-characters

Using the following command.

```
rsync --archive --delete --partial --progress --recursive --no-links --no-devices --quiet source target
```

Using `--no-links` and `--no-devices` already.

Getting the error messages such as this.

```
rsync: mknod "/mnt/shared/backup/var/spool/postfix/dev/log" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
```

Makes `rsync` exit non-zero. This is bad. Breaks my backup script. (I don't want to use ignore this error using `|| true` in case rsync would fail for "legitimate" reasons such as no disk space left.)

In this example, it's a socket file. I don't care about this kind of special files. Can I make rsync ignore/skip those?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rsync -a --no-specials --no-devices` would tell rsync to skip these files. It will still print an information message, but it would return 0 if no other error occurs.

If there's a set of known paths that you don't want to transfer, you could exclude them altogether. Also, do pass the `-x` option to skip all mounted filesystems (including `/dev`, which takes care of the biggest offender), and if there are multiple on-disk filesystems, list all the mount points (e.g. `rsync -ax / /home /destination`).

```
rsync -ax --exclude='/var/spool/postfix/dev/*' / /mnt/shared/backup
```

If none of that is satisfactory, [make a list of files you want to skip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207990). Beware that if some of the file names are under control of an adversary, they could cause some files to be omitted from a backup. For example, if they create a directory whose name is a newline and create a named socket called `*` inside it, then using the output of `find -type s` as an exclude list would result in `/*` being excluded. To prevent such problems, keep problematic names out of the exclude list.

```
{
  cd /path/to/source &&
  find . -name '*[\[?*
]*' -prune -o \
               \( -type b -o -type c -o -type p -o -type s \) -print |
  sed 's/^\.//'
} | rsync -a --exclude-from=- /path/to/source /destination
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use `rsync` together with `find`? Something like this:

```
find /your/source/dir -type s 1> /tmp/ignore-list
rsync <your options> --exclude-from=/tmp/ignore-list /your/source/dir/ /your/destination/dir/
```

Comment: Although the basic principle is good, there are a couple of problems with your proposal. You aren't generating the right paths unless `/your/source/dir` is the root directory: the paths in the ignore list need to be relative to the source directory. Furthermore there is a vulnerability: if an attacker can create a named socket with the path of their choice, they can prevent files from being backed up (e.g. a file called `/*` results in a pattern that excludes all files in that directory).